# Is it possible to use reactJS inside angularJS2

Tags: reactjs, angular

This may sound weird question, but the situation is we now have a component library created in ReactJS, which can be used in backbone and angularJS1, now, we plan to upgrade our angularJS1 project to angularJS2, but I really can not find out way to embed ReactJS into angularJS2.

For angularJS1, I am using directive with link function to integrate reactJS, but no such concept in angularJS2.

So has anyone met such situation before, if so, how did you solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see this going well at all. possibly of interest: [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store)

Comment: Yes, you can use React with Angular. Look here for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718?noredirect=1#comment104273261_54408718