# Connect Angular application with ReactJS app?

Tags: angular, reactjs

I have a Angular app and some part of application I want write in ReactJS.

How can I inject ReactJS app into existing Angular application? I need also bidirectional communication for components.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

INTRO: You can have different environments, different use cases, and different needs. Please remember that there are only some approaches to this solution that can just trigger you to invent something different - a better suited for your use case.

### Two different solutions with example:

- Angular-ReactJS without communication
- Angular-ReactJS with bidirectional communication

All code below is minimal to show a problem on a presented step. On GitHub, you have a complete code to solve a problem, not always 1:1 with the example below because this code is extended.

### Angular-ReactJS without communication

To add ReactJS app into existing Angular application you need to install 5 npm dependencies: `react`, `react-dom`:

```
npm install --save react
npm install --save react-dom
npm install --save-dev @types/react
npm install --save-dev @types/react-dom
npm install --save-dev @types/react-select
```

Next step - we should permit to use `jsx` template in `.tsx` files, so we should edit `tsconfig.json`, and add:

```
{
    ...
   "compilerOptions": {
    …
    "jsx": "react"
}
```

If you use WebStorm you should restart your project because a TSLint shows an error till restart.

To keep a clear structure, I create this structure of directory:

```
angular /
  ng-hero.component.ts // Component in Angular
  react-renderer.component.ts // ReactJS renderer without communication
react /
  react-application.tsx // React init application
  react-hero.tsx // React hero component
app.component.html
app.component.ts
```

Now you need to create a special component in Angular, which will be responsible for embedding the ReactJS application. This component I will call `ReactRendererComponent`. This component is very simple and it has only one template line, a constructor with `import Injector` and one line in `ngOnInit`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-react-renderer',
  template: `<div class="react-container" id="react-renderer"></div>`
})
export class ReactRendererComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ReactApplication.initialize('react-renderer', this.injector);
  }
}
```

Now we need `ReactApplication` component where we initialize the ReactJS app:

```
interface IReactApplication {
  injector: Injector;
}

class ReactApp extends React.Component<IReactApplication, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={'renderer'}>
        <h2>ReactJS component: </h2>
        <br/>
        <ReactHero/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class ReactApplication {

  static initialize(
    containerId: string,
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactApp injector={injector}/>,
      document.getElementById(containerId)
    );
  }
}
```

And we need `ReactHero` component which was used in the example below:

```
class ReactHero extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <span>react-hero works!</span><br/>
        <span>Don't have any data</span>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
export default ReactHero;
```

In Angular App we should use `ReactRenderer` component, so we use:

```
App.component data:
<hr>
<h2>This is Angular</h2>
<img width="100" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
<hr>

<!-- Without data binding -->
<app-react-renderer></app-react-renderer>
```

At this moment we have an Angular app with an embedded ReactJS app, but without any communication. Is it enough for you? If yes, it's all. If you need any kind of communication between both applications, I present you the RxJS option below.

### Angular-ReactJS with bidirectional communication

In this example, you have bidirectional data binding supported by RxJS. You can get this data, and use them in your ReactJS app and Angular app to see all changes. This is enough for a lot of projects, but you can use different options to get this bidirectional communication, for example, you can use Redux for them.

To keep it clear, below I present a complete directory structure for this part:

```
angular /
  hero.service.ts
  ng-hero.component.ts // Component in Angular
  react-bidirectional-renderer.component.ts // ReactJS renderer with bidirectional communication
model /
  hero.ts // interface for Hero object
react-bidirectional
  react-bidirectional-application.tsx // React init application with bidirectional communication
  react-bidirectional-hero.tsx // React hero component with RxJS support
app.component.html
app.component.ts
```

First of all, we create `IHero` interface with data: `/model/hero.ts`

```
export interface IHero {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

In the next step we create `angular/hero.service.ts` service, to use it in the Angular part of application:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  private heroes$: BehaviorSubject<IHero[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor() {
  }

  addHeroes(hero: IHero) { // To add new hero
    const actualHero = this.heroes$.value;
    actualHero.push(hero);
    this.heroes$.next(actualHero);
  }

  updateHeroAge(heroId: number, age: number) { // To update age of selected hero
    const actualHero = this.heroes$.value;
    actualHero[heroId].age = age;
    this.heroes$.next(actualHero);
  }

  getHeroes$(): BehaviorSubject<IHero[]> { // To get BehaviorSubject and pass it into ReactJS
    return this.heroes$;
  }
}
```

And in `app.component.ts` we initialize  with data (Zeus and Poseidon):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public heroesObj$: BehaviorSubject<IHero[]>;
  public heroes: IHero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes$().subscribe((res: IHero[]) => {
      this.heroes = res;
    });

    this.heroesObj$ = this.heroService.getHeroes$();

    this.initHeroes();
  }

  initHeroes() {
    this.heroService.addHeroes({name: 'Zeus', age: 88});
    this.heroService.addHeroes({name: 'Poseidon', age: 46});
  }
}
```

In the next step we should prepare the ReacJS part of the application, so we create `react-bidirectional/react-bidirectional-application.tsx` file:

```
interface IReactBidirectionalApp {
  injector: Injector;
  heroes$: BehaviorSubject<IHero[]>; // We use this interface to grab RxJS object
}

class ReactBidirectionalApp extends React.Component<IReactBidirectionalApp, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      heroes$: this.props.heroes$ // and we pass this data into ReactBidirectionalHero component
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={'renderer'}>
        <h2>ReactJS component (bidirectional data binding): </h2>
        <ReactBidirectionalHero heroes$={this.state.heroes$}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class ReactBidirectionalApplication {

  static initialize(
    containerId: string,
    injector: Injector,
    heroes$: BehaviorSubject<IHero[]>, // This is necessary to get RxJS object
  ) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactBidirectionalApp injector={injector} heroes$={heroes$}/>,
      document.getElementById(containerId)
    );
  }
}
```

In the next step we need `ReactBidirectionalHero` component, so we create it:

```
interface IReactBidirectionalHero {
  heroes$: BehaviorSubject<IHero[]>;
}

class ReactBidirectionalHero extends React.Component<IReactBidirectionalHero, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      heroes: []
    };

    this.addAge = this.addAge.bind(this); // Register function to bump age
    this.addHero  = this.addHero.bind(this); // Register function to add new Hero
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    // In componentDidMount we subscribe heroes$ object
    this.props.heroes$.subscribe((res: IHero[]) => {
      // and we pass this data into React State object
      this.setState({heroes: res});
    });
  }

  addAge(i: number) {
    const temp = this.state.heroes;
    temp[i].age = temp[i].age + 1;

    // In this way we update RxJS object
    this.props.heroes$.next( temp);
  }

  addHero() {
    const temp = this.state.heroes;
    temp.push({name: 'Atena', age: 31});

    // In this way we update RxJS object
    this.props.heroes$.next(temp);
  }

  render() {
    // Hire we render RxJS part of application with addAge button and ADD ATENA button below
    const heroes = this.state.heroes.map((hero: IHero, i) => {
      return <span key={i}>{hero.name} - {hero.age} <button onClick={() => this.addAge(i)}>Add {hero.name} age</button><br/></span>;
    });
    return (
      <span>
        <span>react-hero works!</span><br/>
        {heroes}
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.addHero}>ADD ATENA</button>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

export default ReactBidirectionalHero;
```

Now we need to initialize ReactJS app in Angular application, so we create `angular/react-bidirectional-renderer.component.ts` - it's very simple, with only one changes in comparison to version without communication:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-react-owc-renderer',
  template: `<div class="react-container" id="react-owc-renderer"></div>`
})
export class ReactBidirectionalRendererComponent implements OnInit {
  // Hire we get data from the parent component, but of course, we can also subscribe this data directly from HeroService if we prefer this way
  @Input() heroes$: BehaviorSubject<IHero[]>;

  constructor(public injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // We add only one parameter into initialize function
    ReactBidirectionalApplication.initialize('react-owc-renderer', this.injector, this.heroes$);
  }
}
```

And now we should change a little `ng-hero.component.ts` to see all effect:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-hero',
  template: `
    <div>
      <span>ng-hero works!</span><br/>
      <span *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i = index;">{{hero.name}} - {{hero.age}} - <button (click)="addAge(i)">Add {{hero.name}} age</button><br/></span>
      <br/>
      <button (click)="addHero()">ADD AFRODITA</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgHeroComponent implements OnInit {
  public heroes: IHero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes$().subscribe((res: IHero[]) => {
      this.heroes = res;
    });
  }

  addAge(heroId: number) {
    this.heroService.updateHeroAge(heroId, this.heroes[heroId].age + 1);
  }

  addHero() {
    this.heroService.addHeroes({name: 'Afrodita', age: 23});
  }

}
```

Finally, we change `app.component.html`:

```
App.component data:
<hr>
<h2>This is Angular component: </h2>
<app-ng-hero></app-ng-hero>
<hr>

<!-- With bidirectional data binding-->
<app-react-owc-renderer [heroes$]="heroesObj$"></app-react-owc-renderer>
<hr>
```

And everything should work. If you have any problems, feel free to ask.

Complete repository with this solution you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/qubiack/angular-reactjs).

If you look for a demo, click [hire](https://angular-react.simplysolutions.pl/).

#### Some extra ideas

As you can see I introduce just two approaches to this problem. Here just some tips that could give you a wider view and give you some possibility to find your own better suit solutions for your use case.

- **Store** - share Store between Angular and React application by using Redux - this approach is really nice because you don't need to care about passing data between components. There are some potential problems with this approach - if React application modifies the store and you subscribe to those data please remember about potential problems with NG change detection. Data modified outside of Angular applications could be a problem in some cases so keep it in mind.
- **Iframe** - this is the simplest way to do any kind of just usage ReactJS component in Angular app without bidirectional communication. You can just pass some data in query params of the URL and render React component.
- **Preact.js** - this is really nice approach if you just would like to use a simple react component but you worry about bundle size. Preact gives a lot of React features but it is really small so your build and customer doesn't feel any influence on your technology mirage.

Comment: this seems a lot of work :) any chance to extract the core logic into a reusable lib so it can be reused easily?

Comment: @ABOS it's really simple - First time I lose about 50h with Redux communication, but this version with RxJS is simple, so I add to Stack. But it's good idea to create reusable lib. I will try when I find some time.

Comment: TBH, I did not go through the details :) I would imagine some message communication between angular/react, perhaps that is what you mean using rxjs?

Comment: @ABOS this base on BehaviorSubject (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html) and subscription

Comment: @ kris_IV, thanks for confirming :) So it could be any message system, even generic window postMessage.

Comment: @kris_IV Works awesome. Just got the bidirectional example working. Really big help, thanks so much!

Comment: @kris_IV I have been trying this for two days now but I am trying to get this to work with .js or .jsx instead of using .tsx but as soon as I try .jsx or .js it will just not read it. Complaining about "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type". Do you have any advice for someone who has to add a little react app using the .js/.jsx format and not the .tsx? Reason for this is because we have an Angular app and need to integrate a react app but its been built in .js format by a thirdparty and the only way of making it work is changing it to .tsx. Thank you

Comment: To be honest I don't use this combination from a year so maybe it's some issues with the new version of Angular or React. Genarally the construction is as easy as possible and use only JS object reference but... :) 
Maybe I found some times during a weekend to update this to the newest version of Angular & React. What is your version?

Comment: @kris_IV So its Angular 8 with React 16. So just for a bit of extra context this all works if its .tsx but the issue is that the React app was written in .js so the issue is now changing the file extension to .tsx gives out loads of errors as expected since it has no types and its expecting them. Is there a way to use .tsx on all my files but silence the typescript errors completely, I have tried // @ ts-ignore and a few other things but it doesn't really work, maybe you can advise something better. But being able to use .js or .jsx instead of having to use .tsx would be great!

Comment: @Andrew if I found time to look into it this weekend I will write to you again.

Comment: any update on this for newer react and angular? Wouldn't it be easier to just keep the projects separately in different directories with communication being on the url params layer. i.e. a user id for example? Not too worried about bidirectional communication

Comment: Hi @ChristianMatthew. I usually work with mono repositories so in my case it's always better to keep them together - of course in the proper place as a module. This is just a simple example that shows how it could work. We can do this in many other ways - I had some experience with the Store share approach - in this case, we just share a store between NG & React app. Using URL is another example but Iframe could be a problem for some use cases.

Answer (score -1):

I have been researching patterns to integrate existing angular services in a new react app and I came across this post.

For the bi-directional communication pattern, Could you please explain whats the use of the $injector - since its passed but never used.

Comment: Add this question in comment instead of adding it as an answer