# Wanted to use web component (created in reactJS) in angular 7 application

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular7, web-component

I have used a simple custom element that in React
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-dummy-component]

and i have install in my Angular(Version 7.2) app
app.component.html file is below

```
<my-componet></my-componet> /* This is my Web component */
```

and my app.module.ts is below

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { MyComponent } from 'my-dummy-component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    MyComponent,
    BrowserModule],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but it shows some error in console the html is not rendering the view side.
Is there anything i do in configuration side?

The console error is below :

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module
>   'AppModule'
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:2426)
>       at compiler.js:18646
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   (compiler.js:18615)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.js:26021)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.js:26002)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
>   (compiler.js:25962)
>       at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync
>   (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
>       at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (core.js:17609)
>       at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule
>   (core.js:17792)

my-compononet code is below :

> 'use strict';
>
> Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
>       value: true });
>
> var _react = require('react');
>
> var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
>
> require('./styles.css');
>
> function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ?
>   obj : { default: obj }; }
>
> /*** src/index.js   ***/ var MyComponent = function MyComponent() {
>       return _react2.default.createElement(
>           'h1',
>           null,
>           'Hello from My Component'
>       ); }; exports.default = MyComponent;

Comment: man, your link is broken, can you post your my-component code plix ?

Comment: I have updated with this

Comment: you need seletor with @Component({ selector: my-component }), try to share the link again, maybe help us. I`m trying understand what you want to do, try to explain what you mean

Comment: actually i want add an web component that created in react is used to my angular app. Here is my link https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-dummy-component

Comment: Look hire: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408718/2972087