# How to change React component props in Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, react-redux

I have some problem - I've created React component that makes modal for changing the database from the list. And In the project that I'm working there is an old Angular component that is a button to call this React modal.

In my react modal I have a few fields:

```
export interface ConnectedDatabaseModalState {
list,
isLoading,
selected,
isDatabaseLoading,
visible
}
```

After page is loaded visible is set to true, when I select database there is method to hide modal:

```
    hide() {
    this.setState({
        visible: false,
        isDatabaseLoading: false
    })
}
```

So the modal is not destroyed, it's just hidden. In my angular component, I want to change visible again to true but I don't know how to do it:

```
export class SelectDatabaseButtonComponent extends BasicComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() openDbModalFn: any;

selectDatabase$ = new Subject();
database: Database;


constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectDatabase$.pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)).subscribe(response => {
        //TODO open modal here
    });

    this.subscriptions.add(
        this.store
            .pipe(
                select(selectSelectedDatabase),
                tap((database) => {
                    this.database = database;
                    this.cdr.detectChanges();
                })
            ).subscribe()
    )
}
}
```

And template:

```
<button type="button" id="modalButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="selectDatabase$.next()">
{{ (database?.description) || "Undefined"}}
```

Can someone help me? And also tell me if its good to change react component props in angular component?

What I want to do is call method from react component:

```
show() {
    this.setState({
        visible: true
    })
}
```

In Angular component in place that is //TODO

Comment: There are only unrelated snippets. How Angular and React components are related? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. They should be related somehow, otherwise you can't do this.

Comment: Edited qustion: I want to call method from react component in angular component

Comment: Again, this totally depends on how these two components are related. The question cannot be answered without this being explained. MCVE is a requirement for code-related questions, otherwise. they are considered off-topic and can be closed.

Comment: These components are not related. Modal (React component) is part of all application, it can be open at many views. Button belong only for one view page. Or maybe I don't understand Your question about relation between them.

Comment: You need to make them related in some way. Either Angular app calls `React.render`, or React app calls Angular `bootstrap`, so you could pass a callback, or modal instance or so. This way you can communicate between them. That's how it's usually done. Otherwise you will need to communicate through globals, like `window` events.

Comment: @DominikZ look hire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718