# use react component in angular 4+

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

We have an existing react application (.JS not in TS) that has components that renders SVG graphics with user interactions and we are now thinking to use these components in an angular application. Can we use react components directly in angular 4+  application?.
We have tried to use the available solutions but failed with various of reason...
1)  ngReact --> We are getting support to use this in angularJs 1.* applications , however we are targeting to use in angular 4+  (https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact)
2)  angular-react -->  we tried to use this ,and here we need to convert react application as react library and again we need to create custom modules to understand the angular-react to use the existing components.( https://github.com/Microsoft/angular-react)
do we have any direct solutions to use the existing react components in angular applications? Will that turn out to be a good approach long-term?

Comment: try to convert it to `web component` so that it can be used in any framework. https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html

Comment: I have tried to convert an existing react app to web component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web-component) and tried to use in my angular project but it is not loading the component and giving error "ule parse failed: Unexpected token (5:22) this file type.
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." Do you feel , this is the right approach?.

Comment: look hire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718 this should help you