# How to use React component in Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular6

I have a few components in react and I want to reuse the same in angular 6 application. Can come some suggest me the best way to do this.

Comment: If you look for solutions with data binding you can find it hire:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be third-party helpers for this purpose but they act the same way, React component is rendered and unmounted when needed:

```
@ViewChild('container') containerRef: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
  ReactDOM.render(<ReactComponent/>, this.containerRef.nativeElement);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.containerRef.nativeElement);
}
```

React component can interact with Angular component through props.

Comment: Excellent simple example. Small correction: I believe the render should happen in a `ngAfterViewInit` callback rather than `ngOnInit`, to ensure that the reference provided by the `@ViewChild` has been made available.

Comment: @TylerRick AFAIK it will work in ngOnInit too, as long as `<div #container>` belongs to current component's template. ngAfterViewInit is needed to access fully rendered view, i.e. nested components.