# How can I use a react component in an existing angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I have a react component and want to integrate it into my existing Angular project. My component looks like

```
import React from 'react';


export default function MyComponent (props) {

    return (
        <div>
            {props.message}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I want to use it in angular like that:

```
<MyComponent message="Hello world!"/>
```

Is there any possibility to do something like that?

Comment: you have to install ngReact. Could you please go through this example.  
         https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact

Comment: ngReact is for angularJS only, isn't it?

Comment: It looks like MS is working on something like this, but it is still under development : https://github.com/Microsoft/angular-react

Comment: Yeah, I saw ngReact and angular-react, but both are not fitting for me, so I asked here.

Comment: Check this out.   https://hub.packtpub.com/integrating-angular-2-react/

Comment: these links have demo and implementation. Could you please check these out??                   http://ng2-react-demo.robertjesionek.com/host    https://github.com/jesion/angular2-react

Comment: are these links helped you?

Comment: Actually not, no

Comment: @Andi Hire is a complex solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718 
In this post you can find a github repo with simple demo

Comment: Were you able to get through?

Comment: No, I was not. Can you help me?